# Why the extraneous padding-bottom and/or margin-bottom?

Tags: css

This [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yhEge/) illustrates what this question refers to (full code below).  Note that, even though `#outer-div` should have 0 `padding`, and `#inner-div` should have 0 `margin-bottom`, it appears as though the there's some padding and/or margin between the bottom edges of `#outer-div` and `#inner-div`.

Where does this come from, and, more importantly, how can I suppress it?

**css**

```
html,body,div{margin:0;padding:0;border:0;outline:0}
body{background:white;}
#outer-div{
  background:lightgray;
  margin-top:20px;
  text-align:center;
}
#inner-div{
  background:black;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

**html**

```
<!doctype html>
<body>
<div id="outer-div">
  <div id="inner-div" style="background:black;width:100px;height:100px;">
    <div style="background:orange;margin:1px;width:96px;height:96px;padding:1px;">
      <div style="background:white;margin:1px;width:94px;height:94px;"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inline elements are sensitive to white space and that gap is reserved for descender elements. Adding `vertical-align:top` to #inner-div is one way to fix this:

```
#inner-div {
    background:black;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/yhEge/1/)**

A second way is to set `font-size:0` on the parent element in this **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/yhEge/2/)**.

Comment: Another way is to decrease the height on the inner div set in the style element

Comment: @LiamSorsby - Did you test that?

Comment: Thanks!  Nice to learn answers that work so well.  And yet, surprisingly enough, I find the answer depressing too, cuz it convinces me that I'll never master CSS: there are just too many bewildering/unpredictable quirks like this one for my small brain...  E.g. I'm using `display:inline-block` *only because* it's the only *CSS voodoo* I could find for centering a `div` inside another `div`.  Your answer makes me realize that `display:inline-block` brings all this other unexpected baggage, and I'm dreading the next bizarre quirk it'll spring on me (the night before the deadline, of course)...

Comment: @kjo - Don't get down on yourself, we're all here to learn from one another. The more you use CSS the better you'll get at it. Give it time.

Comment: @Kjo - Unfortunately, the typical way most web devs treat CSS is as so much voodoo. Very few seek out the kind of proper grounding in the subject that would allow them to properly understand what's going on in situations like yours. In fact, the only way I've ever found to get a proper grounding is to read the CSS 2.1 spec itself all the way through, carefully and repeatedly as it's not an easy read, and the implications of what is says are not always immediately obvious.

Comment: @j08691 yes i have tested it however it did mean some of the other elements needed adjusting but nothing major. However i tend to find that margin:0px auto; tends to do the trick centering divs rather then using display: inline-block;

Comment: @LiamSorsby:I don't like `margin:0px auto` because for it to work one also has to specify the `div`'s width; in contrast, with `display:inline-block` the width of the `div` can be omitted, at least if this width can be *deduced* from the widths of the elements it contains.